# How to display yammer thread id conversation?

Tags: multithreading, embed, yammer

I want to display the embedded feeds from a thread message in Yammer, but there's no code script stated in the Yammer docs site - https://developer.yammer.com/docs/embed that you can define the threadID.

The yammer script is only for group, topic or user feeds...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:400px;width:500px;"></div>
<script>
  yam.connect.embedFeed(
      { container: '#embedded-feed',
        network: 'fourleaf.com',
        feedType: 'group',                // can be 'group', 'topic', or 'user'          
        feedId: '123'                     // feed ID from the instructions above
        ,config: {
             defaultGroupId: 3257958      // specify default group id to post to 
        }
  });    
</script>
```

If you create a yammer group and started a thread, you can view this thread by "View Conversation" and you can view the actual thread message similar to this URL = https://www.yammer.com/fourleaf.com/#/Threads/show?threadId=911215172

Question: How to embed this threadID into the web page? Is there a yammer script to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't scope the Yammer embed to a single thread, only various types of feeds. The embed also allows users to create new threads, so even if you could do that, users would put new threads on it anyway.

You are going to have to dip into the APIs to accomplish what you're trying to do, using the Threads endpoint: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/threadsidjson

Comment: Thanks for the response and I also got a confirmation from Yammer group (Microsoft) that this is not available as an embedded script for the current version of their script. My requirement will entail a lot of customization using API and the JSON integration defined on the yammer developer site. I was just hoping that there's a customized code developed already out... in any case, appreciate your time :)